# invoke-rc.d fails in logrotate script, causing log rotation to fail

Tags: apache2, logrotate

I am using Ububtu 20.04 with Apache 2.4.41 and logrotate 3.14.0, which is supposed to be set up such that Apache restarts in the postrotate script. The restart isn't happening, which means that Apache is writing to the wrong log file, which then grows indefinitely (because it has a suffix `.log.1` rather than `.log`).

The postrotate script in the default `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` file looks like this:

```
postrotate
            if invoke-rc.d apache2 status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
                invoke-rc.d apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1; \
            fi;
endscript
```

The problem is that the `invoke-rc.d` command isn't working. If I try it from the command line, the results look like this:

```
# invoke-rc.d apache2 status
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of status.
invoke-rc.d: emulating initscript action "status", returning "unknown"
#
```

Can anyone give any tips on how to resolve this? I don't really know anything about `invoke-rc.d`, what it does or how to configure it. Would a simpler script looking like this work OK?

```
postrotate
    apachectl restart
endscript
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on 22.04 LTS and Apache 2.4.52. Something installed /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d that was blocking services from restarting (exact same symptoms as you posted). I've just added an "exit 0" below the shebang in that file and things are working normally again. Still a mystery as to how that file ended up there.